# SQL Job holds up exe external file after failure

Tags: sql-server, ssis, jobs, ssis-2012, sql-job

I have a SSIS that execute a .exe app with an Execute Process Task. It runs successfully from the VS 2012, but when I deployed the SSIS to a Integration Catalog and if it fails the Job holds up the exe file so I need to reboot the server to unlocked it. How can I prevent this issue?